# is my php interpreter going crazy, or am i the one who is...?

Tags: php, casting

I'm continuing to run into really weird behaviour coding php. Here is an example:

```
<?php 
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Berlin");
$interval1 = (int) 336000;
$interval2 = (int) 1459200;
$interval3 = (int) 17403000;
$interval4 = (int) 43205760;
$interval5 = (int) 84299520;
$week =  (int) 604800;
?>
```

When I run this code, i get an "unexpected T_INT_CAST on line 8 error"
WTF?!! the first 5 casts work perfectly fine. When i don't cast anything, the first 5 expressions result in a integer, the last one in a string. I noticed this while comparing values and obviously got wrong results.

Here is the hex editor output (as requested in a comment):

```
00000000: 3C 3F 70 68 70 20 0A 64  61 74 65 5F 64 65 66 61 
00000010: 75 6C 74 5F 74 69 6D 65  7A 6F 6E 65 5F 73 65 74 
00000020: 28 22 45 75 72 6F 70 65  2F 42 65 72 6C 69 6E 22 
00000030: 29 3B 0A 24 69 6E 74 65  72 76 61 6C 31 20 3D 20 
00000040: 28 69 6E 74 29 20 33 33  36 30 30 30 3B 20 2F 2F 
00000050: 74 65 73 74 20 69 6E 74  65 72 76 61 6C 20 66 72 
00000060: 6F 6D 20 68 74 74 70 3A  2F 2F 65 63 6B 71 75 61 
00000070: 72 74 65 72 73 2E 63 6F  6D 2F 6D 6F 65 74 65 72 
00000080: 77 6F 6C 66 2F 64 69 61  67 72 61 6D 6D 31 2E 68 
00000090: 74 6D 6C 0A 24 69 6E 74  65 72 76 61 6C 32 20 3D 
000000A0: 20 28 69 6E 74 29 20 31  34 35 39 32 30 30 3B 0A 
000000B0: 24 69 6E 74 65 72 76 61  6C 33 20 3D 20 28 69 6E 
000000C0: 74 29 20 31 37 34 30 33  30 30 30 3B 0A 24 69 6E 
000000D0: 74 65 72 76 61 6C 34 20  3D 20 28 69 6E 74 29 20 
000000E0: 34 33 32 30 35 37 36 30  3B 0A 24 69 6E 74 65 72 
000000F0: 76 61 6C 35 20 3D 20 28  69 6E 74 29 38 34 32 39 
00000100: 39 35 32 30 3B 0A 24 77  65 65 6B 20 3D 20 A0 69 
00000110: 6E 74 76 61 6C 28 36 30  34 38 30 30 29 3B
```

Comment: I get no errors running this. PHP 5.3.6

Comment: You're right, that _is_ weird: there are not eight lines of code.

Comment: There are if you include the `<?php`

Comment: You sure you got all the code in there? "The last one in a string", I don't see no strings here.

Comment: open it with a proper editor, you might have some crazy characters there..

Comment: Try to use **[`intval()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php)** function instad of `(int)` casting.

Comment: thanks for your comments! unfortunately, yes i added all the code, i had this in a larger script and then i narrowed it down to just this part. I use textwrangler on a mac, other editor shows exactly the same...i run this on the command line...

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined function  intval() --> this is what i get using intval... my version is PHP 5.3.6

Comment: If you are getting fatal error on intval thats definitely something seriously wrong with your php interpreter. Can you open this file in hex editor and post a screenshot of the part involving last cast?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, i added the hex code above^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see from the hex editor in your php code there is non-breaking space just before intval / (int) casting: (the second space)

`00000100: 39 35 32 30 3B 0A 24 77  65 65 6B 20 3D 20`**`A0`**`69`

get rid of it and your code should work.

Comment: thanks alot man, thats some crazy stuff really :) Never would have figured this out by myself!!

Answer (score 1):

You should think about

```
PHP_INT_SIZE
```

The size of an integer is platform-dependent, although a maximum value of about two billion is the usual value (that's 32 bits signed). 64-bit platforms usually have a maximum value of about 9E18. PHP does not support unsigned integers. Integer size can be determined using the constant PHP_INT_SIZE, and maximum value using the constant PHP_INT_MAX since PHP 4.4.0 and PHP 5.0.5.

When trying to convert from floating point numbers to integers, if the float is beyond the boundaries of integer (usually +/- 2.15e+9 = 2^31 on 32-bit platforms and +/- 9.22e+18 = 2^63 on 64-bit platforms), the result is undefined, since the float doesn't have enough precision to give an exact integer result. No warning, not even a notice will be issued when this happens!

Try to change The PHP_INT_SIZE constant and tell us what's changed

Comment: how is this relevant?? (it was a rhetorical question...)

Comment: Thanks for your answer!....9223372036854775807 == what i get as PHP_INT_MAX constant on my system. apart from that, if the int size were the problem, why am i not getting the error on the highest value?

Comment: i thought about PHP_INT_SIZE because php's behavior in case of using larger integer is , as i said, undefined (even undefined)