# PDO query inside PHP function

Tags: php, function, pdo

I'm making this function where a part of an array should be read, and each value holds a number with which I want to perform a PDO query. This is my following code:

```
function get_topics($array) {

$top = 20; $base = 0;
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {


$getData = $dbc->prepare('SELECT * FROM topics WHERE id = :id LIMIT 1'); 
$getData->execute(array(':id' => $value));

while($row = $getData->fetch()) {



$potential_topic_img = 'members/topic_' . $value . '.jpg'; 
if (file_exists($potential_topic_img)) { $topic_img = $potential_topic_img; } else {      
$topic_img = 'members/0.jpg'; } 




$name = $row['name'];
echo '<div class="topic_div"><img src="' . $topic_img . '" width="80"><br /><span 
style="font-size:10pt;">' . $name . '</span></div>';


} if (++$base == $top) break;

}

}

echo get_topics($some_array);
```

But all I get is an error telling this: "**Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in /home/......**", and it says that the problem is on this line:

```
$getData->execute(array(':id' => $value));
```

What can I be doing wrong?

**EDIT**

I deleted some code and the code is running fine when this is remaining:

```
function get_topics($array) {


foreach ($array as $key => $value) {

echo $value;

  }
}

echo get_topics($user_likes_array);
```

So it's not that $value is empty, the problem seems to be in the line I mentioned in the beginning, since when I move everything below that line, the error message does not change, but it does change when I move that specific line.

Comment: are you sure your $value holds valid content?

Comment: Unexpected anything is caused by a Syntax error, normally a missing semi-colon or bracket but in the code you have posted there is nothing can you provide the full error and code of file

Comment: I guess it's not the line, that causes the error, because there is nothing wrong with it. Would be useful, if you can provide more information.

Comment: @fablife in php every value is valid if it is unset you will get a T_WARNING or T_NOTICE log entry but it will use null or empty in the case of a string

Comment: Use any IDE with decent php syntax highlighting / syntax error detection, you have error somewhere before that line

Comment: I now have the full code in the question.

Comment: @dev-null-dweller, ok I will try.

Comment: And if you have some code copied from some examples/webpages you may have similar problem as here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9053749/is-my-php-interpreter-going-crazy-or-am-i-the-one-who-is

Comment: As soon as I delete the code with the function it all works fine, so it seems to be that the function messes things up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`foreach ($array as $key => $value)` assigns the current element's key to the `$value` variable on each iteration.

Try

```
$getData->execute(':id',$value);
```

Comment: "assigns the current element's key to the $value" you meant `$key`?

Comment: hrm slightly confused as i though PDO supported passing an array into Execute with all parameters you require by what you have shown there is no way to pass more than 1 parameter using the execute and what does the foreach have to so with it as that is doing exactly what was said hrm this seems fishy like sourcing point illegitimately, and im correct http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php Example 2 show that his method was correct?

Comment: Using arrays with PDO.`$data = array('David Cameron', '10 Downing St, 'London');  
$STH = $DBH->("INSERT INTO folks (name, addr, city) values (?, ?, ?);  
$STH->execute($data);'

Answer (score 0):

The code you have posted is correct are you sure your in the right file.

I have just coped your code and sorted out the layout and ran it though my PHP Testing batch and it is correct

**Output from testing batch**

```
G:\Others\Programs\phpApplications>SET PHP_PATH=../php/php.exe

G:\Others\Programs\phpApplications>SET FILE_PATH=../phpApplications/test2.php

G:\Others\Programs\phpApplications>SET LOOP=FALSE

G:\Others\Programs\phpApplications>"../php/php.exe" "../phpApplications/test2.ph
p"

G:\Others\Programs\phpApplications>pause
Press any key to continue . . .
```

**Code i used**

```
<?php

function get_topics($array) {
    $top = 20; 
    $base = 0;
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        $getData = $dbc->prepare('SELECT * FROM topics WHERE id = :id LIMIT 1'); 
        $getData->execute(array(':id' => $value));
        while($row = $getData->fetch()) {
            $potential_topic_img = 'members/topic_' . $value . '.jpg'; 
            if (file_exists($potential_topic_img)) { $topic_img = $potential_topic_img; } else {     
            $topic_img = 'members/0.jpg'; } 

            $name = $row['name'];
            echo '<div class="topic_div"><img src="' . $topic_img . '" width="80"><br /><span     
            style="font-size:10pt;">' . $name . '</span></div>';
        }
        if (++$base == $top) break;
    }
} 
$some_array = array();
echo get_topics($some_array);
```

if there was an error you would have seen it before the pause command is sent to CMD it would have shown the error

**Proof My Tester Works**
for this i just commented out `//` the `$some_array = array()` here is the result

```
G:\Others\Programs\phpApplications>SET PHP_PATH=../php/php.exe

G:\Others\Programs\phpApplications>SET FILE_PATH=../phpApplications/test2.php

G:\Others\Programs\phpApplications>SET LOOP=FALSE

G:\Others\Programs\phpApplications>"../php/php.exe" "../phpApplications/test2.ph
p"

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in G:\Others\Programs\phpApplic
ations\test2.php on line 6

G:\Others\Programs\phpApplications>pause
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: The strange thing is that when I delete only the part of the code with the function the code works fine, so the problem is probable there. I just can't figure out what.

Comment: it's strange is that have you tried commenting out the line that the error is thrown on just to test if it is that line if not try that and post results for us say when i commented out `Line quote here` (ps use backticks for inline code and show the new error or the line number the error moves to

Comment: could it be the section where PDO is set up?

Comment: doubt it normally php would not run if the php.ini is incorrect could you please try my last comment and tell of any change?

Comment: @fablife, I don't think so, because I have used the connection code several times before.